Snowflake.py: RemovedInAirflow3Warning: This module is deprecated. Please use `airflow.providers.common.sql.hooks.sql`
After upgrading airflow from 2.2.0 to 2.9.0 I have been getting the following warning:
snowflake.py:29 RemovedInAirflow3Warning: This module is deprecated. Please use `airflow.providers.common.sql.hooks.sql`.

However, it does not clearly state which changes I need to make in order to switch to the other module. Does anyone know how to fix this warning?

Could you provide which versions of providers are installed please. And sample code from the file showing the operator

It seemed like I was running an old version of apache-airflow-providers-snowflake, namely version 2.2.0.
Updating to the latest version of the package removed the error. (In my case this was version 5.5.0)
